# Mostrar una Fecha en el Front end con Angular

Tags: angular, date

Tengo mi frontend creado con Angular y bootstrap desplegado en Firebase. Mi backend desarrollado con Springboot y Java, deplegado en Render y mi base de datos MySQL en clever cloud.
El asunto es el siguiente: las fechas que ingreso por medio de formularios desde un input type Date:

```
<div class="mb-3 puntos">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Fecha:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1"  [(ngModel)]="educacion.fecha">
</div>
```

Se guardan como tipo fecha en la base de datos:

```
+------------+
| fecha      |
+------------+
| 2022-06-16 |
| 2022-04-02 |
| 2022-05-01 |
+------------+
```

pero al traer o mostrar esa información en mi aplicación:

```
<p style="color: #9fcc40;">{{educacion.fecha}}</p>
```

me devuelve un número extraño para dichas fechas:
1655337600000,1648857600000,1651363200000. Respectivamente.
Es mi primera aplicación y soy muy nuevo en esto así que no tengo idea de donde estaría el problema.
PD:
Agrego una clase del back para que vean como armé la fecha:

```
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;



@Getter @Setter
@Entity
public class Experiencia {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id_exp;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25, message = "no cumple con la longitud")
    private String compania;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25, message = "no cumple con la longitud")
    private String puesto;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 250, message = "no cumple con la longitud")
    private String tarea;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 250, message = "no cumple con la longitud")
    private String img;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaIni;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaFin; 
    
}
```

Comment: Angular, Bootstrap, Firebase, Clever Cloud, Render, Springboot. En serio necesitas todo eso para crear una webapp?

Comment: Xendrian: Es para el curso de Argentina programa y es lo que piden. El back recibe y retorna un el objeto ("experiencia" por ejemplo) que tiene una fecha. Si la guarda bien en la base de datos supongo que debería devolverla igual de bien. deplegada en el local host no me daba ese problema. De todas manera ahí agregué una clase  para que vean si ahí está el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esos número 1655337600000,1648857600000,1651363200000 son los Epoch de las fechas 2022-06-16,2022-04-02,2022-05-01 (milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 GMT / UTC +0), un link a un convertidor
[Epoch convertidor](https://www.epochconverter.com/), es bastante útil para los cálculos de fechas.

En Angular puedes ocupar una pipe para convertir los milisegundos al formato que desees por ejemplo

```
<p style="color: #9fcc40;">{{educacion.fecha | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</p>
```

Comment: Hola Caludio. Gracias. Lo resolví con tu sugerencia solo que el formato que fucionó es de la documentación de angular: date:'d/M/yy'. Pero aún así me retornaba la fecha corrida 24 hs hacia atrás así que tuque que sumarle un día : `{{proyecto.fecha_pro+86400000|date:'d/M/yy'}}`